# Is this regular expression vulnerable to arbitrary file upload?

Tags: php, upload

I'm busy coding a PHP file for secure file uploading of images such as .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .bmp, and .gif

Here is the code:

```
$realname = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

if(!preg_match("/(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif|\.bmp|\.jpeg)$/i",$realname)) {
          die();
}
```

Is there a way to bypass this check to be able to upload a .php file? I've heard of the file.php%00.jpg trick, but that is secured from. Does anyone know of any other methods? Or is the code above safe?

Comment: since file extensions are meaningless, check the actual file type

Comment: sure, `ren nastyvirus.php cutekittens.jpg` and off you go. Thankfully, most servers don't treat .jpg files as PHP scripts, so the raw code would just be send to the client, unlike a php file, which would be executed. Never based security decisions off something a user provided. use server-side file-type determination, e.g. fileinfo, to see if it's really an image, or just something PRETENDING to be an image.

Comment: @Dagon The server uses the file name extension to decide how to handle the file. You can embed PHP code in a perfectly valid image file so better make sure you don’t allow `.php`.

Comment: The server *may* do that, its not the only option.

Comment: @Dagon So what other options you think are there?

Comment: @Gumbo `AddHandler x-httpd-php .bmp .gif .jpg` in the .htaccess file? Stupid, but possible.

Comment: i can tell Apache to serve files with the 2nd letter Z as php if i wanted to, or all files in directory K or files with the date of last friday etc

Comment: @Dagon So the file’s name actually *is* the only clue for the web server to distinguish how to handle a file. There is no directive that says “check the file contents instead of its name”.

Comment: no not just name, any of the environment variables are also available. i don't know what point you are tying to make here?

Comment: @Dagon My point is that it’s foolish to check just the file’s content as the server doesn’t care about it when deciding how to process the file on a request. Thus your suggestion “file extensions are meaningless” is highly dangerous.

Comment: i (and the 4 upvoters) can but disagree. ;-)

Comment: a good post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166762/php-image-upload-security-check-list

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: yes.

But you're in luck, I just wrote this:

```
function checkImageFileIsImage($filepath) {
    $type = exif_imagetype($filepath);
    $allowedTypes = array(
        1,  // [] gif
        2,  // [] jpg
        3   // [] png
    );

    if (!in_array($type, $allowedTypes)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php for more file types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you provide an example of how my code could be bypassed? It will help me learn more.

Comment: Neither John's code nor Grim's is "secure" - http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/05/13/php-code-injection-a-simple-virus-written-in-php-and-carried-in-a-jpeg-image/

Comment: @symcbean Thanks, that's interesting stuff. Using GD to make a copy of the image gets around that problem.

Comment: @symcbean Although I've tried several different methods and I can't get that exploit to "work". Has it been patched in PHP, maybe?

Comment: No it's not a vulnerability in PHP, hence not something which can be fixed by PHP. And you've only been trying for 10 minutes.

Comment: I just did this: echo "<?php file_put_contents('/tmp/bad2', 'whoops'); ?>" >>bad.png     original file still loads as an image, but now executes the code when processed with PHP