# Full Secure Image Upload Script

Tags: php, image, security, file-upload, upload

I don't know if this going to happen, but I will try it.

For past hour I did research on image upload safety. I learned that there a lot of functions to test the upload.

In my project, I need to be safe with images uploaded. There also may be a really big amount of it and it may require a lot of bandwidth, so buying an API is not an option.

So I decided to get a full PHP script for REALLY secure image upload. I also think it will help for many of people out there, because it's impossible to find really secure one. But I am not expert in php, so it's really headache for me to add some functions, so I will ask for this community help to create one full script of REALLY secure image upload.

Really great topics about that are here (however, they are just telling what is needed to do the trick, but not how to do this, and as I said I am not a master on PHP, so I am not able to do this all by myself):
[PHP image upload security check list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166762/php-image-upload-security-check-list)
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form

In summary, they are telling that this is what is needed for security image upload (I will quote from the above pages):

> - Disable PHP from running inside the upload folder using .httaccess.
> - Do not allow upload if the file name contains string "php".
> - Allow only extensions: jpg,jpeg,gif and png.
> - Allow only image file type.
> - Disallow image with two file type.
> - Change the image name. Upload to a sub-directory not root directory.
>
> Also:
>
> - Re-process the image using GD (or Imagick) and save the processed    image. All others are just fun boring for hackers"
> - As rr pointed out, use move_uploaded_file() for any upload"
> - By the way, you'd want to be very restrictive about your upload       folder. Those places are one of the dark corners where many exploits
>     happen. This is valid for any type of upload and any programming
>     language/server. Check
>     https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload
> - Level 1: Check the extension (extension file ends with)
> - Level 2: Check the MIME type ($file_info =    getimagesize($_FILES['image_file']; $file_mime = $file_info['mime'];)
> - Level 3: Read first 100 bytes and check if they have any bytes in the    following range: ASCII 0-8, 12-31 (decimal).
> - Level 4: Check for magic numbers in the header (first 10-20 bytes of    the file). You can find some of the files header bytes from
>     here:
>     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Examples
> - You might want to run "is_uploaded_file" on the    $_FILES['my_files']['tmp_name'] as well. See
>     http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php

Here's a big part of it, but still that's not all. (If you know something more which could help to make the upload even safier, please share.)

**THIS IS WHAT WE GOT NOW**

- Main PHP:

  ```
  function uploadFile ($file_field = null, $check_image = false, $random_name = false) {

  //Config Section    
  //Set file upload path
  $path = 'uploads/'; //with trailing slash
  //Set max file size in bytes
  $max_size = 1000000;
  //Set default file extension whitelist
  $whitelist_ext = array('jpeg','jpg','png','gif');
  //Set default file type whitelist
  $whitelist_type = array('image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png','image/gif');

  //The Validation
  // Create an array to hold any output
  $out = array('error'=>null);

  if (!$file_field) {
    $out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid form field name";           
  }

  if (!$path) {
    $out['error'][] = "Please specify a valid upload path";               
  }

  if (count($out['error'])>0) {
    return $out;
  }

  //Make sure that there is a file
  if((!empty($_FILES[$file_field])) && ($_FILES[$file_field]['error'] == 0)) {

  // Get filename
  $file_info = pathinfo($_FILES[$file_field]['name']);
  $name = $file_info['filename'];
  $ext = $file_info['extension'];

  //Check file has the right extension           
  if (!in_array($ext, $whitelist_ext)) {
    $out['error'][] = "Invalid file Extension";
  }

  //Check that the file is of the right type
  if (!in_array($_FILES[$file_field]["type"], $whitelist_type)) {
    $out['error'][] = "Invalid file Type";
  }

  //Check that the file is not too big
  if ($_FILES[$file_field]["size"] > $max_size) {
    $out['error'][] = "File is too big";
  }

  //If $check image is set as true
  if ($check_image) {
    if (!getimagesize($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'])) {
      $out['error'][] = "Uploaded file is not a valid image";
    }
  }

  //Create full filename including path
  if ($random_name) {
    // Generate random filename
    $tmp = str_replace(array('.',' '), array('',''), microtime());

    if (!$tmp || $tmp == '') {
      $out['error'][] = "File must have a name";
    }     
    $newname = $tmp.'.'.$ext;                                
  } else {
      $newname = $name.'.'.$ext;
  }

  //Check if file already exists on server
  if (file_exists($path.$newname)) {
    $out['error'][] = "A file with this name already exists";
  }

  if (count($out['error'])>0) {
    //The file has not correctly validated
    return $out;
  } 

  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file_field]['tmp_name'], $path.$newname)) {
    //Success
    $out['filepath'] = $path;
    $out['filename'] = $newname;
    return $out;
  } else {
    $out['error'][] = "Server Error!";
  }

   } else {
    $out['error'][] = "No file uploaded";
    return $out;
   }      
  }


  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $file = uploadFile('file', true, true);
   if (is_array($file['error'])) {
    $message = '';
    foreach ($file['error'] as $msg) {
    $message .= '<p>'.$msg.'</p>';    
   }
  } else {
   $message = "File uploaded successfully".$newname;
  }
   echo $message;
  }
  ```
- And the form:

  ```
  <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  <input name="file" type="file" id="imagee" />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
  ```

So, what I am asking is to help by posting snippets of codes which will help me (and everyone else) to make this Image Upload Script to make super secure.
Or by sharing/creating a full script with all the snippets added.

Comment: Since I keep getting upvotes on my answer on this one, let me explain the downvotes on your question: Stack Overflow is a place to find help if you have problems with your code. It's not a place to find improvement on working code ([Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the website for that), and not a place to find or request tutorials either. Simply because (as you see), it takes writing half a book to give a good and proper answer. The amount of views is simply because you offered a bounty on it. Not because everyone needs this :)

Comment: @icecub I am sure there are still people who are looking for this answer and who are glad you have answered it.

Comment: Ye it seems a lot of people are linking to it in other questions because many people don't realise their upload scripts are unsafe. I didn't expect it to get that many upvotes though. It's quite rare these days.

Comment: Thank you for the question Simon. You got my vote. I had to look all over the web for information you already compiled in your question.

Comment: @AuntJamaima Thank you Aunt, I am happy it has helped you

Comment: `if (!in_array($_FILES[$file_field]["type"], $whitelist_type)) {` Is this best practice?

Comment: to bad not Full Secure `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` is vulnerable to Cross site scripting attacks.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

When you start working on a secure image upload script, there are many things to consider. Now I'm no where near an expert on this, but I've been asked to develop this once in the past. I'm gonna walk through the entire process I've been through here so you can follow along. For this I'm gonna start with a very basic html form and php script that handles the files.

HTML form:

```
<form name="upload" action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload: <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
</form>
```

PHP file:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Image succesfully uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Image uploading failed.";
}
?>
```

**First problem: File types**
Attackers don't have to use the form on your website to upload files to your server. POST requests can be intercepted in a number of ways. Think about browser addons, proxies, Perl scripts. No matter how hard we try, we can't prevent an attacker from trying to upload something they're not supposed to. So all of our security has to be done serverside.

The first problem is file types. In the script above an attacker could upload anything they want, like a php script for example, and follow a direct link to execute it. So to prevent this, we implement *Content-type verification*:

```
<?php
if($_FILES['image']['type'] != "image/png") {
    echo "Only PNG images are allowed!";
    exit;
}

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Image succesfully uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Image uploading failed.";
}
?>
```

Unfortunately this isn't enough. As I mentioned before, the attacker has full control over the request. Nothing will prevent him/her from modifying the request headers and simply change the Content type to "image/png". So instead of just relying on the Content-type header, it would be better to also validate the content of the uploaded file. Here's where the php GD library comes in handy. Using `getimagesize()`, we'll be processing the image with the GD library. If it isn't an image, this will fail and therefor the entire upload will fail:

```
<?php
$verifyimg = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

if($verifyimg['mime'] != 'image/png') {
    echo "Only PNG images are allowed!";
    exit;
}

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Image succesfully uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Image uploading failed.";
}
?>
```

We're still not there yet though. Most image file types allow text comments added to them. Again, nothing prevents the attacker from adding some php code as a comment. The GD library will evaluate this as a perfectly valid image. The PHP interpreter would completely ignore the image and run the php code in the comment. It's true that it depends on the php configuration which file extensions are processed by the php interpreter and which not, but since there are many developers out there that have no control over this configuration due to the use of a VPS, we can't assume the php interpreter won't process the image. This is why adding a file extension white list isn't safe enough either.

The solution to this would be to store the images in a location where an attacker can't access the file directly. This could be outside of the document root or in a directory protected by a .htaccess file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Edit: After talking with some other PHP programmers, I highly suggest using a folder outside of the document root, because htaccess isn't always reliable.

We still need the user or any other visitor to be able to view the image though. So we'll use php to retrieve the image for them:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$name = $_GET['name']; // Assuming the file name is in the URL for this example
readfile($uploaddir.$name);
?>
```

**Second problem: Local file inclusion attacks**
Although our script is reasonably secure by now, we can't assume the server doesn't suffer from other vulnerabilities. A common security vulnerability is known as *Local file inclusion*. To explain this I need to add an example code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
   $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
} elseif (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
   $lang = $_GET['lang'];
} else {
   $lang = 'english';
}

include("language/$lang.php");
?>
```

In this example we're talking about a multi language website. The sites language is not something considered to be "high risk" information. We try to get the visitors preferred language through a cookie or a GET request and include the required file based on it. Now consider what will happen when the attacker enters the following url:

[www.example.com/index.php?lang=../uploads/my_evil_image.jpg](http://www.example.com/index.php?lang=../uploads/my_evil_image.jpg)

PHP will include the file uploaded by the attacker bypassing the fact that they can't access the file directly and we're back at square one.

The solution to this problem is to make sure the user doesn't know the filename on the server. Instead, we'll change the file name and even the extension using a database to keep track of it:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `uploads` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `original_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `mime_type` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=0 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['upload']) && !empty($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['error'] == 0)) {

    $uploaddir = 'uploads/';

    /* Generates random filename and extension */
    function tempnam_sfx($path, $suffix){
        do {
            $file = $path."/".mt_rand().$suffix;
            $fp = @fopen($file, 'x');
        }
        while(!$fp);

        fclose($fp);
        return $file;
    }

    /* Process image with GD library */
    $verifyimg = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

    /* Make sure the MIME type is an image */
    $pattern = "#^(image/)[^\s\n<]+$#i";

    if(!preg_match($pattern, $verifyimg['mime']){
        die("Only image files are allowed!");
    }

    /* Rename both the image and the extension */
    $uploadfile = tempnam_sfx($uploaddir, ".tmp");

    /* Upload the file to a secure directory with the new name and extension */
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

        /* Setup a database connection with PDO */
        $dbhost = "localhost";
        $dbuser = "";
        $dbpass = "";
        $dbname = "";
        
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname;

        // Set options
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try {
            $db = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            die("Error!: " . $e->getMessage());
        }

        /* Setup query */
        $query = 'INSERT INTO uploads (name, original_name, mime_type) VALUES (:name, :oriname, :mime)';

        /* Prepare query */
        $db->prepare($query);

        /* Bind parameters */
        $db->bindParam(':name', basename($uploadfile));
        $db->bindParam(':oriname', basename($_FILES['image']['name']));
        $db->bindParam(':mime', $_FILES['image']['type']);

        /* Execute query */
        try {
            $db->execute();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            // Remove the uploaded file
            unlink($uploadfile);

            die("Error!: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        die("Image upload failed!");
    }
}
?>
```

So now we've done the following:

- We've created a secure place to save the images
- We've processed the image with the GD library
- We've checked the image MIME type
- We've renamed the file name and changed the extension
- We've saved both the new and original filename in our database
- We've also saved the MIME type in our database

We still need to be able to display the image to visitors. We simply use the id column of our database to do this:

```
<?php

$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$id = 1;

/* Setup a database connection with PDO */
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "";

// Set DSN
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$dbhost.';dbname='.$dbname;

// Set options
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);

try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $options);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    die("Error!: " . $e->getMessage());
}

/* Setup query */
$query = 'SELECT name, original_name, mime_type FROM uploads WHERE id=:id';

/* Prepare query */
$db->prepare($query);

/* Bind parameters */
$db->bindParam(':id', $id);

/* Execute query */
try {
    $db->execute();
    $result = $db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    die("Error!: " . $e->getMessage());
}

/* Get the original filename */
$newfile = $result['original_name'];

/* Send headers and file to visitor */
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($newfile));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($uploaddir.$result['name']));
header("Content-Type: " . $result['mime_type']);
readfile($uploaddir.$result['name']);
?>
```

Thanks to this script the visitor will be able to view the image or download it with its original filename. However, they can't access the file on your server directly nor will they be able to fool your server to access the file for him/her as they has no way of knowing which file it is. They can't brute force your upload directory either as it simply doesn't allow anyone to access the directory except the server itself.

And that concludes my secure image upload script.

I'd like to add that I didn't include a maximum file size into this script, but you should easily be able to do that yourself.

**ImageUpload Class**
Due to the high demand of this script, I've written an ImageUpload class that should make it a lot easier for all of you to securely handle images uploaded by your website visitors. The class can handle both single and multiple files at once, and provides you with additional features like displaying, downloading and deleting images.

Since the code is simply to large to post here, you can download the class from MEGA here:

[Download ImageUpload Class](https://mega.nz/#!06IWzKga!oOyAoL2ALXxi2odwkxsVkcTtWgik4XNR-4yL3XLR4W4)

Just read the README.txt and follow the instructions.

**Going Open Source**
The Image Secure class project is now also available on my [Github](https://github.com/bjorno43/ImageSecure) profile. This so that others (you?) can contribute towards the project and make this a great library for everyone.

Comment: The `getimagesize()` function clearly states that you should not use this function to validate if an image is an image.  `Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead.` http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: Would this work with multiple uploads? For example I upload 3 images in one form submit?

Comment: @Lachie Well you would have to adept the code to handle multiple files at once, but other than that I don't see why not :) I'm planning to turn this into a library though, so it becomes much easier to use for everyone. However, due to my busy live I don't have an ETA right now :(

Comment: @icecub That's alright. Sounds like a great idea! Good luck :)

Comment: @HugoZonderland You're absolutely right. I'm currently working on a library for this where I've addressed the issue. I will fix it later in the answer as well. Thanks for the headsup :)

Comment: @icecub what library? :-)

Comment: @HugoZonderland It's an ImageUpload class that can handle both single and multipe image file uploads. It's designed to be easy to use as it does all the difficult stuff for you. All you have to do is send the `$_FILES` array to the class. It will create a database table if nessesary as well as a htaccess file etc. I've already finished it. Just working on the documentation for it right now.

Comment: Why do I get undefined index error:
 Undefined index: image in C:\xampp\htdocs\ImageSecure-master\upload.php on line 7. Is there anything to configure? All I did was to extract the zip and go to index.php, it doesn't work

Comment: @Foobarer Did you take the direct Download one or did you pull it from Github? Because the Github one is currently bugged. I enlisted the help of someone else and he messed it up so I'm working on that.

Comment: Yes I did download the Github one, you're right the direct download is working! Btw, is there a way to display the image in img tags? and not div? because my entire page is built on displaying the image in img tags, including all the style and modals etc..

Comment: @Foobarer Yes, just use the "image.php" file as the src attribute value on your image element. Like: `<img src='image.php?id=1'>`. That should work.

Comment: Update: There is a bug in deleteImage function:
There is an extra comma in the SELECT statement after 'original_name' - it should be removed or delete won't work

Comment: What can cause this script to work on development environment, but not on live? I obviously have all the values in `config.php` matching the `php.ini` on my server, yet when I even use the simple code to upload an image, on live environment all I get is a redirection to ImageUpload/upload.php` (the handler) and it shows a blank page. And it doesn't even output any errors, although I have them printed

Comment: @pileup Please direct questions regarding your specific situation towards the email address you'll find in the FAQ part of the readme. This so the list of comments here remains clear. As for your question: Make sure you downloaded the one from Mega and _not_ the one on Github. I had another person help me out on it and he screwed that one up. Still didn't find the time to fix the Github one so it won't work.

Answer (score 9):

To upload files in PHP is easy and secure.
I would recommend learning about:

- [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/function.pathinfo.php) - Returns information about a file path
- [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/function.move-uploaded-file.php) - Moves an uploaded file to a new location
- [copy](http://php.net/manual/function.copy.php) - Copies a file
- [finfo_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) - Creates a new `fileinfo` resource

To upload a file in PHP you have two methods: `PUT` and `POST`.
To use the `POST` method with HTML you need to enable [`enctype`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) on your form like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Then in you PHP you need get your uploaded file with [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) like this:

```
$_FILES['file']
```

Then you need move the file from temp("upload") with `move_uploaded_file`:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], YOUR_PATH)) {
   // ...
}
```

And after you uploaded the file, you need check the file's extension. The best way to do this is using `pathinfo` like this:

```
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

But the extension is not secure because you can upload a file with extension `.jpg` but with mimetype `text/php` and this is a backdoor.
So, I recommend checking the real mimetype with `finfo_open` like this:

```
$mime = finfo_file(finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE), $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

And don't use `$_FILES['file']['type']` because sometimes,
depending your browser and client OS, you may receive
`application/octet-stream` and this mimetype is not the real
mimetype of your uploaded file.

I think you can upload files securely with this scenario.

Sorry for my English, bye!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. However, I don't think it fully answer to my question. I have the script which includes all of your mentioned functions. However, it doesn't make the script fully safe as we can read here http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/risks-of-a-php-image-upload-form. I was hoping that someone will give (no need to write the code, maybe someone already has it) all the functions mentioned on the previous answer, which would make the image upload script secure as possible. However, thanks again for your effort to answer this question.

Comment: @Simon In images part there is lot of things you need to consider while storing it and displaying it. I hope on this platform there will be lot of people helping you on storing part. But regarding displaying part I will recommend you to go through this http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 3):

here is another tip.  Dont rely on the ['type'] element, it is too unreliable.  Instead check the file header itself to see what the file type actually is. Something like so:

```
 <?php


 // open the file and check header

 $tempfile = $FILES['tmp_name'];
                  
 if (!($handle = fopen($tempfile, 'rb')))
 {
   echo 'open file failed';
   fclose($handle);
   exit;

 }else{
  
        $hdr = fread($handle, 12); //should grab first 12 of header
        fclose($handle);                                     
    
 
        //now check the header results
        $subheaderpre = substr($hdr, 0, 12);
        $subheader = trim($subheaderpre);
     
        //get hex value to check png 
        $getbytes = substr($subheader, 0, 8);
        $hxval = bin2hex($getbytes);
     
     
         if ((substr($subheader, 0, 4) == "\xff\xd8\xff\xe0") && (substr($subheader, 6, 5) == "JFIF\x00"))
         {

           //passed jpg test
 
         }elseif($hxval == "89504e470d0a1a" || substr($subheader, 0, 8) == "\x89PNG\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a")
           {

              //passed png test 
                
           }else{
              
                 //fail both 

                 echo 'Sorry but image failed to validate, try another image';
                 exit;                            
                      
                 }//close else elseif else
              
    }//close else ! $handle
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code work fine for me thanks

```
      function gen_uid($l=5){
           return substr(str_shuffle("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"), 10, $l);
      }
      $mime_type = mime_content_type($_FILES['imglink']['tmp_name']);
      $allowed_file_types = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'];
      if (! in_array($mime_type, $allowed_file_types)) {
          // File type is NOT allowed.
        echo "Only PNG and JPG images are allowed!";
        exit;
      }
        $uploaddir = '../uploads/images/';
    
        $name = pathinfo($_FILES['imglink']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $ext  = pathinfo($_FILES['imglink']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    
        $newname = gen_uid(rand(0,30));
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$newname.".webp";
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imglink']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            $imglink = basename($uploadfile);
        } else {
            echo "Image upload failed!";
            die();
        }
```