# React JS and REST API PHP from the scratch

Tags: php, reactjs, api

Hello im literally newbie specially in the world of Web development, I am a 3rd yr student and i wanna ask how to upload an Image file from may FrontEnd React JS to my local server PHP API into mysql?

https://www.positronx.io/react-js-php-upload-and-store-base64-image-tutorial/
heres my refence but i dont understand because this article does not show the connection query side

it will really great to my career if you help me right now

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

don't store base64 image on a sql server

use cloudinary or aws s3 or any other free image storing service...

this might help

[insert base64 image to a mysql table in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44036777/insert-base64-image-to-a-mysql-table-in-php)