# Online image doesnt get through

Tags: php, image, upload, hosting

Offline (locally) my images get trough after uploading, but online I can't. It's probably an easy fix for people that are experienced with PHP. The snippet below is for twitter, but the website is now on my hosting hosted so i dont have the directory 'twitter' anymore (since all the files are just pushed in another directory and not twitter)

Url hosting is: http://uptospace.thomasdebelder.be/
That's also where the files are in my ftp program: directory name: uptospace.thomasdebelder.be

```
move_uploaded_file($fileTmp,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/twitter/'.$root);



if($fileSize <= 2097152) {
            $root = 'users/' . $filename;
            move_uploaded_file($fileTmp,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/http://uptospace.thomasdebelder.be/home.php/'.$root);
            return $root;
           }
```

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Check permissions of the folder.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file($fileTmp,$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/http://uptospace.thomasdebelder.be/home.php/'.$root);` ... ummmmm... that *should* be a filepath, not a mismash of filepath and URL.

Comment: how to fix it? @CD001

Comment: There's a picture above with directory name @CD001

Comment: Depends on what your docroot is, I'm *guess* `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is *probably* something like `/var/www/uptospace.thomasdebelder.be/` ? (you can `var_dump()` it to check.

Comment: Looking at that image - the document root is probably the `public_html` directory - all files would be served from there. If that's the case, the highlighted directory is *outside* the document root - so no files uploaded into that directory could be displayed in the browser,

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509334/full-secure-image-upload-script