# Access files above virtualhost DocumentRoot with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

Is there any way to allow multiple virtual hosts on one server (apache2 on ubuntu 16.40) to serve files from a directory that is above or adjacent to the virtual host's DocumentRoot?

On my server I have the following directories where site_one, and site_two are the document roots.
websites/site_one
websites/site_two
websites/shared_files/images
websites/shared_files/js

I would like to point `http://site_one.com/images/` to `shared_files/images/`

I tried adding `RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ ../shared_files/images/$1` to my .htaccess which produced a 400 bad request error. Adding `Alias "/images" "../shared_files/images"` to  sites-enabled/site_one.com.conf resulted in a 403 forbidden error.

I can access files with php using either `include('../shared_files/file.php)` or simply `chdir(../shared_files/)` but I would prefer not to load images and other static files that way.

Comment: You need to add the ubuntu user (owner) of `site_one` to the group of `shared_files`. Allowing it to access that directory. If you are in your hosting dir `var/www` for example, type `ls -l` to see which user and groups own the dirs. Then just check which group owns `shared_files` and add the user of `site_one` to that group. More about that here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/79565/how-to-add-existing-user-to-an-existing-group

Comment: But if this is about securily handling images for your users, I would suggest you check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509334/full-secure-image-upload-script/38712921#38712921

Comment: @icecub `ls -l` shows all the directories having the same user and group.

Comment: In that case `Alias "/images" "../shared_files/images"` should've worked, unless you're using symlinks, in which case you also need to add `Options +FollowSymlinks`.

Comment: @icecub I tried adding `Options +FollowSymlinks` but still get 403 error. I am setting this up to reduce and simplify dealing with duplicate files, not for user image security, but incidentally I've also been looking for something like your image upload script so thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to replace the relative `"../images"` path in the virtualhost alias with an absolute path such as: `Alias "/images" "/var/www/shared_files/images"`

Comment: I would prefer an .htaccess solution. If anyone comes up with one I would gladly accept that as the correct answer.