# PHP file upload full proof file validation

Tags: php, validation, file-upload

I need help in validating uploaded file whether they are one of these image `.jpeg, .jpg, .png`. After researching I found that these methods are useless like `exif_image, finfo, getimagesize` they can be by-passed by using/adding some magic numbers in files and can be spoofed. Is there any full proof way to do this?

Comment: I guess the link below can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509334/full-secure-image-upload-script/38712921

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Full Secure Image Upload Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509334/full-secure-image-upload-script)