# What does Laminas\InputFilter\FileInput do exactly?

Tags: file-upload, zend-framework3, laminas

I've been researching [Laminas documentation](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-inputfilter/file-input/) for their FIleInput class and i haven't found a decent explanation of what those filters and validators actually do.

I'm building a community website and planning to let users upload files and i want to apply security checks on those uploaded files, i've researched a lot about this and i'm planning to do the Image security checks that i found in a lot of threads in StackOverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166762/php-image-upload-security-check-list) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509334/full-secure-image-upload-script)), but i want to do some other checking/validating for non-image uploaded files.

So can Laminas\InputFilter\FileInput actually do that? or what does it do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that user is sending a proper file image with the below:

```
    public function addInputFilter()
    {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter\InputFilter();

        // File Input
        $fileInput = new InputFilter\FileInput('image-file');
        $fileInput->setRequired(true);

        // Define validators and filters as if only one file was being uploaded.
        // All files will be run through the same validators and filters
        // automatically.
        $fileInput->getValidatorChain()
            ->attachByName('filesize',      ['max' => 204800])
            ->attachByName('filemimetype',  ['mimeType' => 'image/png,image/x-png'])
            ->attachByName('fileimagesize', ['maxWidth' => 100, 'maxHeight' => 100]);

        // All files will be renamed, e.g.:
        //   ./data/tmpuploads/avatar_4b3403665fea6.png,
        //   ./data/tmpuploads/avatar_5c45147660fb7.png
        $fileInput->getFilterChain()->attachByName(
            'filerenameupload',
            [
                'target'    => './data/tmpuploads/avatar.png',
                'randomize' => true,
            ]
        );
        $inputFilter->add($fileInput);

        $this->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
    }
```

A list of Input Filters is here:

- Count
- crc32
- ExcludeExtension
- ExcludeMimeType
- Exists
- Extension
- FilesSize
- Hash
- ImageSize
- IsCompressed
- IsImage
- Md5
- MimeType
- NotExists
- Sha1
- Size
- Upload
- UploadFile
- WordCount

Docs: https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-validator/validators/file/intro/